# Executando audio em php

Tags: php, html5-audio

Como é possivel carregar uma tag audio com o arquivo fora do meu servidor

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../../spool/teste.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

No mesmo nivel da minha pasta www tenho uma pasta chamada musicas, onde tem as musicas que quero reproduzir. eu consigo utilizar um file_exists para saber se tenho acesso e também consigo dar unlink, porém não consigo carregar pelo src. como posso fazer isso?
também não é possivel caso eu passe o caminho exato C:/wamp/Musica/teste.mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue acessar arquivos fora do diretório **www** do servidor Web. Isto ocorre também por uma questão de segurança.

Ou você deve copiar os arquivos que deseja compartilhar para dentro deste diretório ou então, nas configurações do servidor Web, mude o diretório raiz. Com o XAMPP, por exemplo, no arquivo `httpd.conf` a configuração está na linha:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

Comment: Isso funciona do mesmo modo para linux também? por exemplo é possivel eu definir a pasta C: como diretorio raiz assim podendo ter acesso a todos os arquivos?

Comment: Funciona, no Linux você poderia definir sua pasta `/home/brunosilva/music` por exemplo como raiz do servidor. Mas atente para a questão do *usuário* que roda o servidor web. Ele tem que de alguma maneira ter permissão de ler estes diretórios/arquivos. Supondo que o usuário que roda o serviço fosse, digamos, `www-data`, ou seus diretórios e subdirs tem que permitir à este usuário lê-los (porque pertenceriam ao `brunosilva`) ou tem que permitir a leitura a todos (o que é uma possível falha de segurança).